# A different tax rate for one WooCommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, invoice, tax

I want to change the Tax rate from 20% to 9% just for an product. So for example for the product "X" I need to have 9% VAT tax.

I am using WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips plugin, and I would like to get this new rate on the Pdf invoice too.

How should I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WooCommerce > Settings > Tax > Reduce rate rates, create an entry with a rate of 9%:

[image]

Save.

Then in Products > Edit your selected product, and select the reduce tax rate:

[image]

Save. You are done…

---

> You can also add "Additional Tax Classes" in WooCommerce > Settings > Tax.
>   You will be able to add a tax class by line:

[image]

Save. Once done, You will have an additional tab by tax class, and you will do it the sam way as above.

Comment: I did this but, in the invoice the tax is 0